# Meaning of "which nothing else could impart to a man of moral perceptions

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The consciousness of acting
> right diffused a serenity over his manners, **which nothing else
> could impart to a man of moral perceptions** like his, and which
> refined his sense of every surrounding blessing.

THE MYSTERIES OF UDOLPHO by Ann Radcliff

I'm trying to understand the bold sentence. I think "which" refers to "the consciousness of the acting". This makes me understand the the whole idea as " only the consciousness of acting can impart this serenity to a man of moral like him"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your understanding of the idea, but given our agreement on that point, "which" must refer to "serenity over his moral manners." So: (1) nothing else (other than the consciousness of acting right) could impart serenity over moral manners to a man of moral perceptions like his, and (2) serenity over moral manners refined his sense of every surrounding blessing.

Answer (score 2):

In simple English, I understand the text to mean:

The awareness of doing the right thing
left him with a calm, rewarding feeling
which nothing else could rival
in a man aware of right and wrong as he was,
and which helped him appreciate the good things of life.